# Given quintic polynomial $f$ - If ${\rm Gal}(f)$ has an element of order 3 then it is not solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$  be a quintic irreducible polynomial, $E$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Assume ${\rm Gal}(E/\mathbb Q)$ has a subgroup (or an element) of order $3$. Prove $f$ is not solvable by radicals over $\mathbb Q$

I'm trying to show that ${\rm Gal}(E/\mathbb Q)$ is not a solvable group, perhaps using [this claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075225/f-irreducible-polynomial-with-p-2-real-roots-rightarrow-gal-mathbbq-f) but can't find a way to show it. I have tried to regard ${\rm Gal}(E/\mathbb Q)$ as a subgroup of $S_5$ and then I know that an element of order $3$ is a cycle, say WLOG $(1\space2\space3)$. Can I conclude something from that?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should write any partial progress you've made in the question.

Comment: $ckefa I have added some details

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/837042/348926

Comment: @LukasHeger Can't see how this helps. I'm only given one element of order $3$ and the other one in the group is its inverse

Comment: @BulGali If it wasn't clear, the Galois group acts transitively on the set of roots (since the polynomial is irreducible)

Comment: Because the polynomial is irreducible, the degree is divisible by 5. So there's an element of order 5. Conjugate the element of order 3 by that.

Comment: @LukasHeger Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof that a $3$-cycle and a $5$-cycle generate $A_5$.
Let $G$ be the subgroup of $A_5$ generated by a $3$-cycle $\sigma$ and a $5$-cycle $\tau$. Note that there are $\binom{5}{3}=10$ subgroups of order $3$ in $A_5$. By the Sylow theorems, the normalizer of a $3$-Sylow has index $10$, so  it consists of $6$ elements.
As we have $N_{G}(\langle \sigma \rangle) \subset N_{A_5}(\langle \sigma \rangle)$, $\tau$ (and in fact any $5$-cycle) does not normalize $\langle \sigma\rangle$. Hence the index $[G:N_{G}(\langle \sigma \rangle)]$ is divisible by $5$. But by Sylow theory, we have $[G:N_{G}(\langle \sigma \rangle)] \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, thus we get that $10$ divides $[G:N_{G}(\langle \sigma \rangle)]$ and hence $|G|$. So we get that $30$ divides $|G|$. But if $|G|=30$, then $[A_5:G]=2$, so $G$ is normal in $A_5$, contadicting the fact that $A_5$ is simple. Thus $G=A_5$, as claimed.

Why does this solve the question? Well, since $f$ is irreducible, we have that $5$ divides $[E:\Bbb Q]$, so $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\Bbb Q)$ contains an element of order $5$, i.e. a $5$-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It is a classic theorem that the maximal solvable transitive subgroup of $S_5$ consists of all transforms

$$n\mapsto an+b$$ where we have arithmetic modulo $5$. Here $0\leq b\leq 4$ and $1\leq a \leq 4$. This group has order $20$. From this the claim follows.